# How to reference a Class List with another class?

Tags: python, spyder

I am setting up a script that will extract data from excel and return it in lists. Right now I am trying to be able to reorganized the data into smaller lists that have a common attribute. (Such as: A list that has the indices of the rows that contained, 'Pencil') I keep having the smaller list returning None.

I've checked and the lists that extract the data are working fine. But I cant seem to get the smaller lists working.

```
#Create a class for the multiple lists of Columns
class Data_Column(list):
     def Fill_List (self,col): #fills the list
         for i in range(sheet.nrows):
             self.append(sheet.cell_value(i,col))
#Create a class for a specific list that has data of a common artifact
class Specific_List(list):
     def Find_And_Fill (self, listy, word):
         for i in range (sheet.nrows):
             if listy[i] == word:
                 self.append(I)
#Initiate and Populate lists from excel spreadsheet
date = Data_Column()
date.Fill_List(0)

location = Data_Column()
location.Fill_List(1)

name = Data_Column()
name.Fill_List(2)

item = Data_Column()
item.Fill_List(3)

specPencil = Specific_List()
print(specPencil.Find_And_Fill(item,'Pencil'))
```

I expected a List that contained the indices where 'Pencil' was found such as [1,6,12,14,19].
The actual output was: None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to take the print out of the very last line.

```
specPencil.Find_And_Fill(item,'Pencil')
print(specPencil)
```

I knew it was a simple fix

Comment: For the record, if you `return self` from `Find_And_Fill`, the original code would work.